# how to arrange a data based on two columns

Tags: r

I have a data with many columns , a portion can be find below

```
df<- structure(list(Mine = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L), .Label = c("IsMineBro", "IsMineBroCanMeriMerate", "None"
), class = "factor"), IMers = c(103L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 162L, 
170L, 170L, 284L, 308L, 320L, 444L, 558L, 801L, 801L, 814L, 814L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1015L, 1032L, 1032L, 1032L, 1032L, 1122L), namet = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 24L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 19L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 8L, 
12L, 21L, 6L, 17L, 5L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 18L), .Label = c("A0A0J9YU05", 
"Bir22227", "Bir50516-1", "Bir50518", "Bir60930", "Bir60931", 
"Bir61078", "Bir62523", "Bir62814", "Bir70315", "Bir71V06", "Bir7TBirE2", 
"Bir80ZI9", "Bir810K5", "Bir8BH43", "Bir921J0", "Bir99KC8", "Bir9Z1G3", 
"F2Z471", "G3UX26", "J3BirMG3", "Mer3YUN8", "Mer3YZT5", "O88342"
), class = "factor"), data1 = c(59.2, 10.7, 10.7, 10.7, 52.3, 
16.7, 16.7, 40.5, 32.2, 116.6, 120.6, 35.6, 23.3, 23.3, 66.3, 
66.3, 50, 50, 132.3, 102.3, 102.3, 102.3, 102.3, 11), data2 = c(70.7, 
13.3, 13.3, 13.3, 55.8, 21.1, 21.1, 42.5, 28.6, 124.9, 104.9, 
32.1, 25.3, 25.3, 79.3, 79.3, 55.5, 55.5, 164, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
10), data3 = c(59.5, 15.8, 15.8, 15.8, 66.5, 14.9, 14.9, 28.9, 
26.2, 117.6, 117.6, 33.7, 23.8, 23.8, 81.7, 81.7, 44.1, 44.1, 
159.3, 159.3, 159.3, 159.3, 159.3, 20)), .Names = c("Mine", "IMers", 
"namet", "data1", "data2", "data3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I want to put those that have similar "Imers" together and seperate them by a ; . Then in another column I want to put their corresponding "mine"

since the other columns are the same among all the similar IMers, I will only represent the rest based on IsMine bro of the Unique Imers.

An expected output is like this

```
output <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 15L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 14L, 
10L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 13L), .Label = c("Bir22227", "Bir50516-1", 
"Bir50518", "Bir60930;G3UX26;Mer3YZT5;Mer3YUN8", "Bir60931;J3BirMG3", 
"Bir62523;Bir7TBirE2", "Bir62814", "Bir70315;Bir61078", "Bir71V06;Bir810K5", 
"Bir8BH43", "Bir921J0", "Bir99KC8", "Bir9Z1G3", "F2Z471", "O88342;Bir80ZI9;A0A0J9YU05"
), class = "factor"), Lebel = structure(c(2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("IsMineBro", 
"IsMineBroCanMeriMerate", "IsMineBro;IsMineBroCanMeriMerate;None", 
"IsMineBro;None", "IsMineBro;None;None;None", "None"), class = "factor"), 
    data1 = c(59.2, 10.7, 52.3, 16.7, 40.5, 32.2, 116.6, 120.6, 
    35.6, 23.3, 66.3, 50, 132.3, 102.3, 11), data2 = c(70.7, 
    13.3, 55.8, 21.1, 42.5, 28.6, 124.9, 104.9, 32.1, 25.3, 79.3, 
    55.5, 164, 20, 10), data3 = c(59.5, 15.8, 66.5, 14.9, 28.9, 
    26.2, 117.6, 117.6, 33.7, 23.8, 81.7, 44.1, 159.3, 159.3, 
    20)), .Names = c("ID", "Lebel", "data1", "data2", "data3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Let me give an example so it will be easy to understand the problem

Lets look at the first row of the `df` 
I look at IMers, I see it is 103 and it is unique (there is not any other 103) so I keep the row as I presented in the output

I look at the second row, I see there are three 123. Then I look at the `Mine` column, I see IsMineBro, IsMineBroCanMeriMerate and None. 
I will get the names in that order in another column

```
it becomes O88342; Bir80ZI9; A0A0J9YU05
```

and I put their corresponding Mine in the other column the same way

```
IsMineBro;IsMineBroCanMeriMerate; None
```

And the data1, data2 etc. Gets only the row of `IsMineBro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can get a solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    arrange(Mine) %>%
    group_by(IMers) %>%
    summarise(ID = paste(namet, collapse = ';'),
              Lebel = paste(Mine, collapse = ';'),
              data1 = max(data1),
              data2 = max(data2),
              data3 = max(data3))

# A tibble: 15 x 6
   IMers                                ID                                         Lebel data1 data2 data3
   <int>                             <chr>                                         <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   103                          Bir22227                        IsMineBroCanMeriMerate  59.2  70.7  59.5
 2   123        O88342;Bir80ZI9;A0A0J9YU05         IsMineBro;IsMineBroCanMeriMerate;None  10.7  13.3  15.8
 3   162                          Bir921J0                                          None  52.3  55.8  66.5
 4   170                 Bir70315;Bir61078                                IsMineBro;None  16.7  21.1  14.9
 5   284                          Bir62814                                     IsMineBro  40.5  42.5  28.9
 6   308                        Bir50516-1                                     IsMineBro  32.2  28.6  26.2
 7   320                            F2Z471                                          None 116.6 124.9 117.6
 8   444                          Bir8BH43                                     IsMineBro 120.6 104.9 117.6
 9   558                          Bir50518                                     IsMineBro  35.6  32.1  33.7
10   801                 Bir71V06;Bir810K5 IsMineBroCanMeriMerate;IsMineBroCanMeriMerate  23.3  25.3  23.8
11   814               Bir62523;Bir7TBirE2                                IsMineBro;None  66.3  79.3  81.7
12  1009                 Bir60931;J3BirMG3                                IsMineBro;None  50.0  55.5  44.1
13  1015                          Bir99KC8                                     IsMineBro 132.3 164.0 159.3
14  1032 Bir60930;G3UX26;Mer3YZT5;Mer3YUN8                      IsMineBro;None;None;None 102.3  20.0 159.3
15  1122                          Bir9Z1G3                                     IsMineBro  11.0  10.0  20.0
```

Comment: I accepted your answer. Do you mind to add something extra? counting the number of strings per each row (the ID column) for example the first one has 1, the second one has 3, the third one has 1, the fourth of has 2 etc etc

Comment: After `data3 = max(data3)` add a line which says `count = n()` within the `summarise` call